# 18.04 Strange noise in headphones

Tags: 18.04, sound, asus, headphones, audio-jack

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my [Asus UX433F](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-14-UX433FN/Tech-Specs/)  PC. Whenever I plug in my headphones I hear an unpleasant sound. The sound goes off after a few seconds and restarts playing as soon as I play music or start a video.

How can I troubleshoot and solve this?

after running `sudo lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1461
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1461
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 145
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b1210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at b122a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df9 (rev 30)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1461
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b1229000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9ded (rev 30) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
```

Thank you!

Comment: Since PC makers sometimes use different components, please help us with identifying your sound hardware with _sudo lspci -v && lsmod | grep snd_ Please run that, then highlight the results, copy with Ctrl-Shift-C , come back here, do [edit], and paste the results into your question.to add that so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]